# How to fix "ReferenceError: navigator is not defined during" build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tinymce

I have a Next.js project with TypeScript.  I take a reference from official [document](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-pm-bundle/) resulting to the followings.

BundledEditor.jsx:

```
// ** https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-pm-bundle/ **//
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react'

// remove ssr, otherwise will cause ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

// TinyMCE so the global var exists
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce'

// DOM model
import 'tinymce/models/dom/model'

// Theme
import 'tinymce/themes/silver'

// Toolbar icons
import 'tinymce/icons/default'

// Editor styles
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css'

// importing the plugin js.
// if you use a plugin that is not listed here the editor will fail to load
import 'tinymce/plugins/advlist'
import 'tinymce/plugins/anchor'
import 'tinymce/plugins/autolink'
import 'tinymce/plugins/autoresize'
import 'tinymce/plugins/autosave'
import 'tinymce/plugins/charmap'
import 'tinymce/plugins/code'
import 'tinymce/plugins/codesample'
import 'tinymce/plugins/directionality'
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons'
import 'tinymce/plugins/fullscreen'
import 'tinymce/plugins/help'
import 'tinymce/plugins/image'
import 'tinymce/plugins/importcss'
import 'tinymce/plugins/insertdatetime'
import 'tinymce/plugins/link'
import 'tinymce/plugins/lists'
import 'tinymce/plugins/media'
import 'tinymce/plugins/nonbreaking'
import 'tinymce/plugins/pagebreak'
import 'tinymce/plugins/preview'
import 'tinymce/plugins/quickbars'
import 'tinymce/plugins/save'
import 'tinymce/plugins/searchreplace'
import 'tinymce/plugins/table'
import 'tinymce/plugins/template'
import 'tinymce/plugins/visualblocks'
import 'tinymce/plugins/visualchars'
import 'tinymce/plugins/wordcount'

// importing plugin resources
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons/js/emojis'

// Content styles, including inline UI like fake cursors
/* eslint import/no-webpack-loader-syntax: off */
// import contentCss from 'tinymce/skins/content/dark/content.css'

import contentCss from '!!raw-loader!tinymce/skins/content/default/content.min.css'
import contentUiCss from '!!raw-loader!tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css'

export default function BundledEditor(props) {
  const { init, ...rest } = props

  // note that skin and content_css is disabled to avoid the normal
  // loading process and is instead loaded as a string via content_style
  return (
    <Editor
      init={{
        ...init,
        skin: false,
        content_css: false,
        content_style: [contentCss, contentUiCss, init.content_style || ''].join('\n')
      }}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}
```

I just import it on other file like this:

```
import BundledEditor from './BundledEditor';
```

It works, but if refresh, the page will show this error:

> ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

So I change the import way like this:

```
// remove ssr, otherwise will cause ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

const BundledEditor = dynamic(() => import('../BundledEditor'), {
  ssr: false
})
```

then fix the issue.

But when I try to type `yarn build` to check the project.

It shows error:

```
info  - Collecting page data ...ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at /Users/motogod19/4iDPS/Sphere/sphere-brand-dev/node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.js:961:23
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/motogod19/4iDPS/Sphere/sphere-brand-dev/node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.js:31525:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at 3868 (/Users/motogod19/4iDPS/Sphere/sphere-brand-dev/.next/server/pages/apps/campaign/BundledEditor.js:28:33)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/motogod19/4iDPS/Sphere/sphere-brand-dev/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /apps/campaign/BundledEditor
```

I'm not familiar with Next.js, is any dynamic import should I do ?

Comment: try renaming BundleEditor to DynamicBundleEditor const DynamicBundledEditor = dynamic and then render it like this

Comment: Thanks for the help, I update like this `const DynamicBundledEditor = dynamic(() => import('./BundledEditor'), {
  ssr: false
})` and then type yarn build still get the same error.

Comment: very interesting, any chance we could get a minimum example sandboxed somewhere?

Comment: I jsut create a repo for my issue https://github.com/motogod/testmce, still looking for the solution, if you have time please check it, thanks.

Comment: Hi @Morton ! It's a very bad idea to use `typeof window !== "undefineed"` as suggested by the accepted answer. Check out the new answer you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigator is not defined` means that you are bundling the code for server side, which do not have the browser related APIs. You need to bundle this for the client side (that is, for the browser).

The issue is because `tinymce` do not support ssr (as evident from https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3709)

---

Since you are using Next.js 13 and `pages` router, change your `BundleEditor.jsx` to below:

```
// ** https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-pm-bundle/ **//
import React from 'react';

import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    require('tinymce/tinymce');
    require('tinymce/models/dom/model');
    require('tinymce/themes/silver');
    require('tinymce/icons/default');
    require('tinymce/plugins/advlist');
    require('tinymce/plugins/anchor');
    require('tinymce/plugins/autolink');
    require('tinymce/plugins/autoresize');
    require('tinymce/plugins/autosave');
    require('tinymce/plugins/charmap');
    require('tinymce/plugins/code');
    require('tinymce/plugins/codesample');
    require('tinymce/plugins/directionality');
    require('tinymce/plugins/emoticons');
    require('tinymce/plugins/fullscreen');
    require('tinymce/plugins/help');
    require('tinymce/plugins/image');
    require('tinymce/plugins/importcss');
    require('tinymce/plugins/insertdatetime');
    require('tinymce/plugins/link');
    require('tinymce/plugins/lists');
    require('tinymce/plugins/media');
    require('tinymce/plugins/nonbreaking');
    require('tinymce/plugins/pagebreak');
    require('tinymce/plugins/preview');
    require('tinymce/plugins/quickbars');
    require('tinymce/plugins/save');
    require('tinymce/plugins/searchreplace');
    require('tinymce/plugins/table');
    require('tinymce/plugins/template');
    require('tinymce/plugins/visualblocks');
    require('tinymce/plugins/visualchars');
    require('tinymce/plugins/wordcount');
    require('tinymce/plugins/emoticons/js/emojis')
}

// Editor styles
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css';

// Content styles, including inline UI like fake cursors
/* eslint import/no-webpack-loader-syntax: off */
// import contentCss from 'tinymce/skins/content/dark/content.css'

import contentCss from '!!raw-loader!tinymce/skins/content/default/content.min.css';
import contentUiCss from '!!raw-loader!tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css';

export default function BundledEditor(props) {
    const { init, ...rest } = props;

    // note that skin and content_css is disabled to avoid the normal
    // loading process and is instead loaded as a string via content_style
    return (
        <Editor
            init={{
                ...init,
                skin: false,
                content_css: false,
                content_style: [contentCss, contentUiCss, init?.content_style || ''].join('\n'),
            }}
            {...rest}
        />
    );
}
```

Both `npm run dev` and `npm run build` works fine.

```
$ npm run build

> testmce@0.1.0 build
> next build

- info Linting and checking validity of types  
- info Creating an optimized production build  
- info Compiled successfully
- info Collecting page data  
- info Generating static pages (4/4)
- info Finalizing page optimization  

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      3.39 kB        80.3 kB
├   └ css/00a586533d958f8e.css             1.73 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B            76.9 kB
├ ○ /404                                   182 B          77.1 kB
├ λ /api/hello                             0 B            76.9 kB
└ ○ /BundledEditor                         473 kB          550 kB
    └ css/3191dae2698bb014.css             11.8 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              77.6 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-63157d71ad419e09.js   45.2 kB
  ├ chunks/main-c6c319de9f7d0316.js        29.4 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-5fbdfbcdfb555d2f.js  296 B
  ├ chunks/webpack-1f3c29ac3f0dceed.js     2.06 kB
  └ css/876d048b5dab7c28.css               706 B

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I use v13 and pages router and I think `setShouldRender` may be the point, but still get same error (npm run dev is working)

Comment: @Morton I have updated my answer to use `dynamic`. Can you check if it works for you?

Comment: If I remove { Editor }, I still need the import to render `<Editor />`, I change it to be `const { Editor } = dynamic(() => import('@tinymce/tinymce-react'), {
  ssr: false
})` still not working

Comment: I create a repo only for my situation https://github.com/motogod/testmce, if you have time please check it, many thanks.

Comment: change to `const { DynamicBundledEditor } = dynamic(() => import('@tinymce/tinymce-react'), {
  ssr: false
})` still has the same error, also it can not work when `npm run dev`, the code will print `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string`, it looks like `const { DynamicBundledEditor }` and reurn `<DynamicBundledEditor />` on BundledEditor.jsx is incorrect

Comment: @Morton Have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Robin,  I learn a lot from your help. It works. Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because the `tinymce` does not seem to be server-side rendering friendly, as executing browser specific code in the component body or at import. That has been said, using `typeof window !== 'undefined'` as suggested in the other answer is not recommended at all, as it will very likely cause a [hydration error](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error#common-causes).

Using `dynamic` import with `ssr:false` should work. In your case, it did not, because you have `BundledEditor` in `pages` directory, so it's considered as a page for `/BundledEditor` causing another error.

Just move `BundledEditor` outside `pages`, in a `components` folder for example, at the same level as `pages`, and import it like so:

```js
// pages/index.tsx

import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const DynamicBundledEditor = dynamic(() => import("../../components/BundledEditor"), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Comment: So your point different from others is move the `BundledEditor` file out of pages folder, for instance, components folder. Thanks for your kindly suggestion, I will try it too.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Let me know please :)